# XML Data missing when project gets published

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, publish

I completed my first Flash/Actionscript project and I feel ready to publish it.
Here is the problem:

In my program I refer to several values which are defined in one XML file and are loaded in via code.
When I test my program in Flash everything works fine.
But after I publish my project all parameters which should be defined by the XML are setted to zero. It seems like the published fla file doens't find the XML it should refer to. I want the program to run on computers which don't have the original XML file on their hard drive.

Which settings do I have to apply to fix this?
What should I do?

Thanks ;)

Comment: how did you published? exe or swf?

Comment: i tried to publish swf and html, both with the above described result

Comment: you need to place the xml file with swf file or you need upload to somewher and access it through internet.

Comment: So there is no option to run the program if you are offline and you dont have the XML on your hard drive?

Comment: Thats a pitty! Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Like Ohlilie said, when you publish a SWF that loads in an XML file (using `URLLoader`), you need to always have the XML file in the same relative location to the SWF so that it can found and loaded.

However, there are a few solutions to avoid needing to do this.

First of all, if you use AIR, you can package a bunch of files together, and you simply need to include your XML file in your package. If your intended target platform is desktop, then using AIR is a good solution.

If you don't use AIR, and you just want to run SWFs locally, you can embed the XML in the SWF at compile time. Like this:

```
[Embed(source='myXmlFile.xml', mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public static const MyXml:Class; 

// To load the XML:
var xml:XML = new XML(new MyXml());
```

Lastly, a quick but not as maintainable solution is to embed the XML inline within AS3:

```
var xml:XML = <xml><etc/></xml>
```

You could put this in an .as file which gets included in your AS3 using [`include`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#include), which gets you very close to the `embed` XML file syntax.

Note that embedding the XML does mean that the only way to update the XML is to re-compile the SWF itself. However, you could also enhance all these approaches to first check if an external XML file exists at an expected location (using `URLLoader` as before), and only if the XML file is not found then it falls back to the embedded XML as a default. This way you get a SWF that can work on its own, or can be configured using an external XML file.